# Exception when using CATiledLayer - can somebody interpret this stacktrace?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have written a PDF reader. It renders one page at a time. Using a swipe gesture the user can switch to the next page. If I keep switching pages fast enough (really, really fast) I get the error below. I tried to debug I do not get an exception in Monotouch.
Can somebody read sensible information from the stacktrace?

```
  Stacktrace:

      at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00004>
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00004>
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31
      at testBrowser.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/itest/Documents/Develop/testBrowser/testBrowser/Main.cs:14
      at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001d, 0x00043>

    Native stacktrace:

        0   testBrowser                    0x000be9db mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 343
        1   testBrowser                    0x0000e7a6 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 313
        2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9118c46b _sigtramp + 43
        3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
        4   QuartzCore                          0x03035232 CABackingStoreCopyRenderImage + 64
        5   QuartzCore                          0x03035060 _ZN2CA6Render17copy_render_valueEPKvPFP12CGColorSpacevE + 212
        6   QuartzCore                          0x0303326d -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) _copyRenderLayer:layerFlags:commitFlags:] + 434
        7   QuartzCore                          0x030330b4 CALayerCopyRenderLayer + 55
        8   QuartzCore                          0x030311d2 _ZN2CA7Context12commit_layerEP8_CALayerjjPv + 122
        9   QuartzCore                          0x030310e1 CALayerCommitIfNeeded + 323
        10  QuartzCore                          0x03031069 CALayerCommitIfNeeded + 203
        11  QuartzCore                          0x03031069 CALayerCommitIfNeeded + 203
        12  QuartzCore                          0x0301f7b9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 1395
        13  QuartzCore                          0x0301f0d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
        14  QuartzCore                          0x0304f7d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x00dfafbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d900e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d58bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d58240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d58161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
        20  GraphicsServices                    0x03eb8268 GSEventRunModal + 217
        21  GraphicsServices                    0x03eb832d GSEventRun + 115
        22  UIKit                               0x01bf242e UIApplicationMain + 1160
        23  ???                                 0x09d31c41 0x0 + 164830273
        24  ???                                 0x09d31b7a 0x0 + 164830074
        25  ???                                 0x09d3157d 0x0 + 164828541
        26  ???                                 0x09d314b9 0x0 + 164828345
        27  ???                                 0x09d31514 0x0 + 164828436
        28  testBrowser                    0x0000e56a mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1360
        29  testBrowser                    0x001c961b mono_runtime_invoke + 137
        30  testBrowser                    0x001cb2d7 mono_runtime_exec_main + 714
        31  testBrowser                    0x001cabfd mono_runtime_run_main + 812
        32  testBrowser                    0x00095354 mono_jit_exec + 200
        33  testBrowser                    0x0027d299 main + 3494
        34  testBrowser                    0x00003009 _start + 208
        35  testBrowser                    0x00002f38 start + 40

    Debug info from gdb:

    warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-x86.double-abi-stret-trampoline.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-x86.double-abi-stret-trampoline.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(gc.x86.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(gc.x86.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(zlib-helper.x86.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(zlib-helper.x86.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: Could not find object file "/var/folders/Ny/NyElTwhDGD8kZMqIEeLGXE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccvRqNHg.o" - no debug information available for "template.m".

    warning: .o file "/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_divdi3.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_moddi3.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_moddi3.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_umoddi3.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/libgcc.a(_umoddi3.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser
    warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/itest/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/08D29A1D-AB54-49CC-9C55-FE763BB6BC37/testBrowser.app/testBrowser"
    warning: Couldn't open object file '/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.o)'
    Attaching to process 17837.
    Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
    Reading symbols for shared libraries ........................................................................................................................... done
    0x91131459 in read$UNIX2003 ()
      15                                 0x9114ba12 in __workq_kernreturn ()
      14                                 0x9114ba12 in __workq_kernreturn ()
      13                                 0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
      12 "com.apple.CFSocket.private"    0x911450c6 in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
      11                                 0x911260fa in mach_msg_trap ()
      10                                 0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
       9                                 0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
       8                                 0x911b9a7e in poll$UNIX2003 ()
       7                                 0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
       6 "WebThread"                     0x911260fa in mach_msg_trap ()
       5                                 0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
       4                                 0x91126136 in semaphore_wait_trap ()
       3                                 0x911260fa in mach_msg_trap ()
       2 "com.apple.libdispatch-manager" 0x9114c982 in kevent ()
    *  1 "com.apple.main-thread"         0x91131459 in read$UNIX2003 ()

    Thread 15 (process 17837):
    #0  0x9114ba12 in __workq_kernreturn ()
    #1  0x9114bfa8 in _pthread_wqthread ()
    #2  0x9114bbc6 in start_wqthread ()

    Thread 14 (process 17837):
    #0  0x9114ba12 in __workq_kernreturn ()
    #1  0x9114bfa8 in _pthread_wqthread ()
    #2  0x9114bbc6 in start_wqthread ()

    Thread 13 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
    #1  0x91153d62 in _pthread_cond_wait ()
    #2  0x911559f8 in pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 ()
    #3  0x0022d0bc in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x101, timeout=0x0, alertable=1, poll=0) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1614
    #4  0x0022ce70 in _wapi_handle_wait_signal_handle (handle=0x101, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1557
    #5  0x00242a6e in WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x101, timeout=4294967295, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wait.c:205
    #6  0x00201f39 in async_invoke_thread (data=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threadpool.c:1485
    #7  0x00203836 in start_wrapper (data=0xda7eaa0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
    #8  0x00244c76 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c680) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
    #9  0x002746eb in GC_start_routine (arg=0xa20aea0) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
    #10 0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #11 0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 12 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911450c6 in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
    #1  0x00d8ccbc in __CFSocketManager ()
    #2  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #3  0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 11 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911260fa in mach_msg_trap ()
    #1  0x91126867 in mach_msg ()
    #2  0x00dfb4a6 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
    #3  0x00d58874 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
    #4  0x00d58240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
    #5  0x00d58161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
    #6  0x01378162 in +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] ()
    #7  0x01342d4c in -[NSThread main] ()
    #8  0x01342cd8 in __NSThread__main__ ()
    #9  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #10 0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 10 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
    #1  0x91153d62 in _pthread_cond_wait ()
    #2  0x911559f8 in pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 ()
    #3  0x0022d0bc in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x10f, timeout=0x0, alertable=1, poll=0) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1614
    #4  0x0022ce70 in _wapi_handle_wait_signal_handle (handle=0x10f, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1557
    #5  0x00242a6e in WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x10f, timeout=4294967295, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wait.c:205
    #6  0x001fee14 in async_invoke_io_thread (data=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threadpool.c:369
    #7  0x00203836 in start_wrapper (data=0xda38170) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
    #8  0x00244c76 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c604) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
    #9  0x002746eb in GC_start_routine (arg=0xa20aea0) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
    #10 0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #11 0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 9 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
    #1  0x91153d62 in _pthread_cond_wait ()
    #2  0x911559f8 in pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 ()
    #3  0x0022d0bc in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x10f, timeout=0x0, alertable=1, poll=0) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1614
    #4  0x0022ce70 in _wapi_handle_wait_signal_handle (handle=0x10f, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1557
    #5  0x00242a6e in WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x10f, timeout=4294967295, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wait.c:205
    #6  0x001fee14 in async_invoke_io_thread (data=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threadpool.c:369
    #7  0x00203836 in start_wrapper (data=0xd9305b0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
    #8  0x00244c76 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c490) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
    #9  0x002746eb in GC_start_routine (arg=0xa20af60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
    #10 0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #11 0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 8 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911b9a7e in poll$UNIX2003 ()
    #1  0x00250781 in mono_poll (ufds=0x716c000, nfds=2, timeout=-1) at ../../../../mono/utils/mono-poll.c:8
    #2  0x001ff1cd in socket_io_poll_main (p=0x35db20) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threadpool.c:495
    #3  0x00203836 in start_wrapper (data=0xd9305b0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
    #4  0x00244c76 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c414) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
    #5  0x002746eb in GC_start_routine (arg=0xa20af60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
    #6  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #7  0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 7 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
    #1  0x91153d62 in _pthread_cond_wait ()
    #2  0x911559f8 in pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 ()
    #3  0x0022d0bc in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x101, timeout=0x0, alertable=1, poll=0) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1614
    #4  0x0022ce70 in _wapi_handle_wait_signal_handle (handle=0x101, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/handles.c:1557
    #5  0x00242a6e in WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x101, timeout=4294967295, alertable=1) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wait.c:205
    #6  0x00201f39 in async_invoke_thread (data=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threadpool.c:1485
    #7  0x00203836 in start_wrapper (data=0xd917340) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
    #8  0x00244c76 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c2a0) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
    #9  0x002746eb in GC_start_routine (arg=0xa20af60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
    #10 0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #11 0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 6 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911260fa in mach_msg_trap ()
    #1  0x91126867 in mach_msg ()
    #2  0x00dfb4a6 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
    #3  0x00d58874 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
    #4  0x00d58240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
    #5  0x00d58161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
    #6  0x04f7e423 in RunWebThread ()
    #7  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #8  0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 5 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911540a6 in __semwait_signal ()
    #1  0x9117fee5 in nanosleep$UNIX2003 ()
    #2  0x9117fe23 in usleep$UNIX2003 ()
    #3  0x002774e0 in monotouch_pump_gc ()
    #4  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #5  0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 4 (process 17837):
    #0  0x91126136 in semaphore_wait_trap ()
    #1  0x0015b189 in finalizer_thread (unused=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/gc.c:1026
    #2  0x00203836 in start_wrapper (data=0x6e33210) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
    #3  0x00244c76 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c034) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
    #4  0x002746eb in GC_start_routine (arg=0x6ff8f60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
    #5  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #6  0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 3 (process 17837):
    #0  0x911260fa in mach_msg_trap ()
    #1  0x91126867 in mach_msg ()
    #2  0x0011cfb2 in mach_exception_thread (arg=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini-darwin.c:138
    #3  0x9115385d in _pthread_start ()
    #4  0x911536e2 in thread_start ()

    Thread 2 (process 17837):
    #0  0x9114c982 in kevent ()
    #1  0x9114d09c in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()
    #2  0x9114c559 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
    #3  0x9114c2fe in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
    #4  0x9114bd81 in _pthread_wqthread ()
    #5  0x9114bbc6 in start_wqthread ()

    Thread 1 (process 17837):
    #0  0x91131459 in read$UNIX2003 ()
    #1  0x000beb8b in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=11, ctx=0xbfffb560) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini-exceptions.c:1826
    #2  0x0000e7a6 in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=11, info=0xbfffb520, context=0xbfffb560) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:4846
    #3  <signal handler called>
    #4  0x03035274 in CA::Render::Shmem::copy_image ()
    #5  0x03035232 in CABackingStoreCopyRenderImage ()
    #6  0x03035060 in CA::Render::copy_render_value ()
    #7  0x0303326d in -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) _copyRenderLayer:layerFlags:commitFlags:] ()
    #8  0x030330b4 in CALayerCopyRenderLayer ()
    #9  0x030311d2 in CA::Context::commit_layer ()
    #10 0x030310e1 in CALayerCommitIfNeeded ()
    #11 0x03031069 in CALayerCommitIfNeeded ()
    #12 0x03031069 in CALayerCommitIfNeeded ()
    #13 0x0301f7b9 in CA::Context::commit_transaction ()
    #14 0x0301f0d0 in CA::Transaction::commit ()
    #15 0x0304f7d5 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback ()
    #16 0x00dfafbb in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
    #17 0x00d900e7 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
    #18 0x00d58bd7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
    #19 0x00d58240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
    #20 0x00d58161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
    #21 0x03eb8268 in GSEventRunModal ()
    #22 0x03eb832d in GSEventRun ()
    #23 0x01bf242e in UIApplicationMain ()
    #24 0x09d31c41 in ?? ()
    #25 0x09d31b7a in ?? ()
    #26 0x09d3157d in ?? ()
    #27 0x09d314b9 in ?? ()
    #28 0x09d31514 in ?? ()
    #29 0x0000e56a in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method=0x80a83f4, obj=0x0, params=0xbfffed1c, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:4733
    #30 0x001c961b in mono_runtime_invoke (method=0x80a83f4, obj=0x0, params=0xbfffed1c, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:2615
    #31 0x001cb2d7 in mono_runtime_exec_main (method=0x80a83f4, args=0x9faec00, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:3581
    #32 0x001cabfd in mono_runtime_run_main (method=0x80a83f4, argc=0, argv=0xbfffee54, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:3355
    #33 0x00095354 in mono_jit_exec (domain=0x6f91e58, assembly=0x9b4b480, argc=1, argv=0xbfffee50) at ../../../../mono/mini/driver.c:1094
    #34 0x0027d299 in main ()

    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================


    Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone-3/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've allowed a backing store to get collected before iOS is done with it.  More specifically an image or a layer.

Comment: When changing pages I recreate the CATiledLayer but before I set the current CATIledLayer's delegate to NULL and dispose the layer. Should I not do this? What is the best way to stop CATiledLayer's background actions?

Comment: Oh and btw: If I dispose something that gets accessed later, there's usually a nice exception which I don't get here.Meanwhile I commented out the CATiledLayer and the issue is gone...but how to fix it!?

Comment: And AGAIN you were right. *sigh*
But I still don't understand why. I set the CATIledLayer's delegate to NULL then I removed the layer from the super layer, then I called Dispose() on the layer. Randomly it crashes. If I remove the Dispose() it works. So yeah, something still tries to use the layer but what!? Well...at least it works now and the Dispose() is not required, garbage collection is doing a good job.